# Will these two sql transactions deadlock? (/Resolve with 1 rollback)

Tags: sql, database, transactions, innodb, deadlock

Say I had a purchase transaction doing something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE `USER` SET `Money` = `Money - '100';
UPDATE `ITEMS` SET `Item` = `Item` + '1';
COMMIT;
```

And unfortunately at the same time a cron ran, giving interest on everyone's existing balance:

```
UPDATE `USER` SET `Money` = `Money` + '50';
```

(either wrapped in a transaction or just a single autocommit)

Would that cause a deadlock in any case? (Which may be resolved by a rollback of one by the dbms).

Comment: Depends on which dbms you're using.

Comment: InnoDB/MySQL, -but what would make one dbms deadlock other another not?

Comment: Some dbms never deadlock. (E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)

Comment: Don't you need `UPDATE ... WHERE user_id = ...`?

Comment: Depends on the system, (but yes I agree transaction 1 would most likely be a single user purchase so would have it). Both cases should be safe from deadlock though?

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock requires :

- two distinct transactions
- where each of those two is already holding some lock
- and where each of those two are in need of yet another one
- (and that needed other one is already held by the other transaction).

Theoretically that could happen in your scenario, if your locks are not on the entire table (but more fine-grained) and if the access strategies for updating your USERS table are different (processing physical pages of the table in a different order).  It would be seriously odd in this case, but otoh it is never a good idea to depend in any way on assumed internal behaviour of query processing.